# Does the Hogwarts Express continue past Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

[image]

According to the map included in the 20th edition of the Philosopher's Stone, there are tracks after the Hogsmeade Station.

Does that mean that the Hogwarts Express continues past Hogwarts?

Comment: Considering that Hogsmeade Station is depicted as a pull-through station, they'll need some place (a loop, a wye or a turntable) to reverse (at least) the locomotive before sending the train back.

Comment: The train?  No.  An express train is one that goes from one location to another without any stops.  But the traintracks might continue on, and the Hogwarts Express train might be used for other purposes during other periods.

Answer (score 7):

There is an incident in *Half-Blood Prince* which may shed light on this. At the end of Chapter Seven, Malfoy paralyzes Harry and hides him with the Invisibility Cloak. He then says:

> “I don’t reckon they’ll find you till the train’s back in London,” he said quietly. “See you around, Potter... or not.”

At the beginning of the next chapter, while still stuck on the train, Harry thinks the following:

> Ron and Hermione would think that he had left the train without them. Once they arrived at Hogwarts and took their places in the Great Hall, looked up and down the Gryffindor table a few times, and finally realized that he was not there, he, no doubt, would be halfway back to London.

Both of these quotes, while not explicitly saying so, seem to imply that the train goes straight back to London, or at the very least that there are not *many* further stops after Hogwarts.

Comment: @DavidW That sounds more like [the other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/242990/100430).