# Are platform 9 3/4 and the Hogwart's Express tracks used for other trains besides the Hogwart's Express?

Tags: harry-potter

[image]

The Hogwarts Map included in the 20th anniversary edition of Philosophers Stone claims the Hogwarts Station is called "Hogsmeade Station".

Does that mean that other trains besides Hogwarts Express use it? Are the tracks used for non-school purposes?

Comment: Dupe of [How does the line to Hogwarts fit in to the UK national rail network?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184504/how-does-the-line-to-hogwarts-fit-in-to-the-uk-national-rail-network)

Comment: Dupe of [Where do the other platforms lead?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15764/where-do-the-other-platforms-lead)